# Is there a way to reduce the amount of code for RMSProp

Tags: python

I have some code for a simple recurrent neural network and would like to know if there is a way for me to reduce the amount of code necessary for my update stage. The code I have so for:

```
class RNN(object):
    def__init___(self, data, hidden_size, eps=0.0001):
        self.data = data
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.weights_hidden = np.random.rand(hidden_size, hidden_size) * 0.1 # W
        self.weights_input = np.random.rand(hidden_size, len(data[0])) * 0.1 # U
        self.weights_output = np.random.rand(len(data[0]), hidden_size) * 0.1 # V 
        self.bias_hidden = np.array([np.random.rand(hidden_size)]).T  # b
        self.bias_output = np.array([np.random.rand(len(data[0]))]).T # c

        self.cache_w_hid, self.cache_w_in, self.cache_w_out = 0, 0, 0
        self.cache_b_hid, self.cache_b_out = 0, 0
        self.eps = eps

    def train(self, seq_length, epochs, eta, decay_rate=0.9, learning_decay=0.0):
         # Other stuff
         self.update(seq, epoch, eta, decay_rate, learning_decay)
         # Other Stuff

    def update(self, seq, epoch, eta, decay_rate, learning_decay):
        """Updates the network's weights and biases by applying gradient
        descent using backpropagation through time and RMSPROP. 
        """
        delta_nabla_c, delta_nabla_b,\
        delta_nabla_V, delta_nabla_W, delta_nabla_U = self.backward_pass(seq)

        eta = eta*np.exp(-epoch*learning_decay)

        self.cache_w_hid += decay_rate * self.cache_w_hid \
                           + (1 - decay_rate) * delta_nabla_W**2
        self.weights_hidden -= eta * delta_nabla_W / (np.sqrt(self.cache_w_hid) + self.eps)

        self.cache_w_in += decay_rate * self.cache_w_in \
                          + (1 - decay_rate) * delta_nabla_U**2         
        self.weights_input -= eta * delta_nabla_U / (np.sqrt(self.cache_w_in) + self.eps)

        self.cache_w_out += decay_rate * self.cache_w_out \
                           + (1 - decay_rate) * delta_nabla_V**2
        self.weights_output -= eta * delta_nabla_V / (np.sqrt(self.cache_w_out) + self.eps)

        self.cache_b_hid += decay_rate * self.cache_b_hid \
                          + (1 - decay_rate) * delta_nabla_b**2
        self.bias_hidden -= eta * delta_nabla_b / (np.sqrt(self.cache_b_hid) + self.eps)

        self.cache_b_out += decay_rate * self.cache_b_out \
                          + (1 - decay_rate) * delta_nabla_c**2
        self.bias_output -= eta * delta_nabla_c / (np.sqrt(self.cache_b_out) + self.eps)
```

For every variable under `#RMSProp` follows the update rule, namely:

```
cache = decay_rate * cache + (1 - decay_rate) * dx**2
x += - learning_rate * dx / (np.sqrt(cache) + eps)
```

I have `cache_` all declared followed by `self.weight_` or `self.bias_` and would like to have this written more compactly. I was looking at using `zip()` but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: Where is this code? In a script/module, a class or a function? The use of `self` indicates a method, but the use of globals like `cache_w_hid` points to a module or a class.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. I wrote this get a better understanding of how classes work in python. I've updated the post to include the entire function where that part of the code is located. `cache_` is only found in `def update` and nowhere else in the entire class.

Comment: That answers my question perfectly. Thanks. Working on answer now.

Comment: Wait, you set cache to zero every time on purpose?

Comment: I didn't notice that until now, I will make the change for it to be initially set to zero then to reuse those new values. Thank you

Comment: Then the cache vars will have to be instance attributes that are set in `__init__` as well. That is why I was confused by the first piece of code you posted.

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edits. Also, please resolve the discrepancy in the cache update. In your code it is `cache_* += ...`. In your rule it is `cache_* = ...`.

Comment: Gave you one more version to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your question, I am guessing that you are trying to improve readability/elegance over any other kind of optimization here.

You can introduce a function to implement the update rule, then call it once for each variable. The trick here is that Python lets you access attributes by name, so you can pass in the name of your cache and weights attribute instead of the value. This will let you update the value for future passes:

```
def update_rule(self, cache_attr, x_attr, decay_rate, learning_rate, dx):
    cache = getattr(self, cache_attr)
    cache = decay_rate * cache + (1 - decay_rate) * dx**2
    setattr(self, cache_attr, cache)

    x = getattr(self, x_attr)
    x += - learning_rate * dx / (np.sqrt(cache) + self.eps)
    setattr(self, x_attr, x)

def update(self, seq, epoch, eta, decay_rate, learning_decay):
    """Updates the network's weights and biases by applying gradient
    descent using backpropagation through time and RMSPROP. 
    """
    delta_nabla_c, delta_nabla_b,\
    delta_nabla_V, delta_nabla_W, delta_nabla_U = self.backward_pass(seq)

    eta = eta*np.exp(-epoch*learning_decay)

    self.update_rule('cache_w_hid', 'weights_hidden', decay_rate, eta, delta_nabla_W)
    self.update_rule('cache_w_in', 'weights_input', decay_rate, eta, delta_nabla_U)
    self.update_rule('cache_w_out', 'weights_output', decay_rate, eta, delta_nabla_V)
    self.update_rule('cache_b_hid', 'bias_hidden', decay_rate, eta, delta_nabla_b)
    self.update_rule('cache_b_out', 'bias_output', decay_rate, eta, delta_nabla_c)
```

In fact, you can save additional parameters and avoid exposing what is basically a private method by putting `update_rule` into `update`. This will expose the namespace of `update` to `update_rule` when it is called, so you do not have to pass in `decay_rate` and `learning_rate`:

```
def update(self, seq, epoch, eta, decay_rate, learning_decay):
    """Updates the network's weights and biases by applying gradient
    descent using backpropagation through time and RMSPROP. 
    """

    def update_rule(cache_attr, x_attr, dx):
        cache = getattr(self, cache_attr)
        cache = decay_rate * cache + (1 - decay_rate) * dx**2
        setattr(self, cache_attr, cache)

        x = getattr(self, x_attr)
        x += - eta * dx / (np.sqrt(cache) + self.eps)
        setattr(self, x_attr, x)

    delta_nabla_c, delta_nabla_b,\
    delta_nabla_V, delta_nabla_W, delta_nabla_U = self.backward_pass(seq)

    eta = eta*np.exp(-epoch*learning_decay)

    update_rule('cache_w_hid', 'weights_hidden', delta_nabla_W)
    update_rule('cache_w_in', 'weights_input', delta_nabla_U)
    update_rule('cache_w_out', 'weights_output', delta_nabla_V)
    update_rule('cache_b_hid', 'bias_hidden', delta_nabla_b)
    update_rule('cache_b_out', 'bias_output', delta_nabla_c)
```

Finally, if you really wanted, you could use `zip` to put the calls to `update_rule` into a loop. Notice that for this version, the order of the calls has been changed to match the order of the values returned by `self.backward_pass`. Personally I would not use this last version unless you really had a lot of updates to do because it is starting to look obfuscated in addition to the fact that it is very sensitive to the result of `backward_pass`.

```
def update(self, seq, epoch, eta, decay_rate, learning_decay):
    """Updates the network's weights and biases by applying gradient
    descent using backpropagation through time and RMSPROP. 
    """

    def update_rule(cache_attr, x_attr, dx):
        cache = getattr(self, cache_attr)
        cache = decay_rate * cache + (1 - decay_rate) * dx**2
        setattr(self, cache_attr, cache)

        x = getattr(self, x_attr)
        x += - eta * dx / (np.sqrt(cache) + self.eps)
        setattr(self, x_attr, x)

    dx = self.backward_pass(seq)

    eta = eta*np.exp(-epoch*learning_decay)

    cache_attrs = ('cache_b_out', 'cache_b_hid', 'cache_w_out', 'cache_w_hid', 'cache_w_in')
    x_attrs = ('bias_output', 'bias_hidden', 'weights_output', 'weights_hidden', 'weights_input')

    for args in zip(cache_attrs, x_attrs, dx):
        update_rule(*args)
```